# Module object is not iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror

When running `python3 main.py :80/` is returning a `TypeError: 'module' object is not iterable`

I know this type of question is already being asked in community, but none of the previous questions could be fixed my issue.

**main.py:**

```
import ipaddress, concurrent.futures, requests, sys

def ipv4(ipaddress):
     net4 = ipaddress.ip_network('120.52.22.96/27')
     for host in net4.hosts():
          ipaddress = [print(str(host))]

def scan(ipaddress):
     headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36'}
     r = requests.get('http://' + ipaddress + sys.argv[1], headers=headers, timeout=0.5)
     print(r.url, r.status_code, r.headers)

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
 executor.map(scan, ipaddress)
```

**Error Message:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 14, in <module>
executor.map(scan, ipaddress)
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 600, in map
fs = [self.submit(fn, *args) for args in zip(*iterables)]
TypeError: 'module' object is not iterable
```

Comment: I have an answer ready, but before I post it, can I please check **why** you want to do this scan?

Comment: Actually, what Bastien Harkins has posted already contains the basic gist of what I was going to post, so maybe I don't need to post my answer. Just make sure that you have a legitimate purpose for scanning the target network, because most network services intended for public use should be advertised in some way that doesn't depend on scanning sequentially through IP addresses to find them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning a module object to the `executor.map`, if you need to change the variable value in a function, use the `global` keyword.

```
def ipv4(ipaddress):
     global ipaddress
     net4 = ipaddress.ip_network('120.52.22.96/27')
     for host in net4.hosts():
          ipaddress = [print(str(host))]
```

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
 executor.map(scan, ipaddress)
```

Comment: Why would you use `global` with a function parameter?

Comment: @alaniwi I just did it in the easy way, I thought about appending all `host` to a list and then return it, but I'm not sure what the code need to do.

Answer (score 1):

Naming variables or parameters with imported module names is not good practice, because it will cause you lots of errors.

The following generates the `ipv4` list first, than applies `scan` to each element using `map`

```
import ipaddress, concurrent.futures, requests, sys

def ipv4():
    net4 = ipaddress.ip_network('120.52.22.96/27')
    IP_list = []
    for host in net4.hosts():
         IP_list.append(str(host))
    return IP_list

def scan(IP):
     headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36'}
     r = requests.get('http://' + IP + sys.argv[1], headers=headers, timeout=0.5)
     print(r.url, r.status_code, r.headers)

ipv4_list = ipv4()

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
    executor.map(scan, ipv4_list)
```

Comment: This should work. I just hope it is not abused and that there is not some network admin in Beijing wondering why people are scanning their network.